# How to pass `ApplyConfig` to `tf.Apply()` in `hashicorp / terraform-exec`?

Tags: go, terraform

I am trying to add a **target** to **terraform apply** command using golang sdk for terraform in [hashicorp](https://github.com/hashicorp)/**[terraform-exec](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec)**
Ideally, the equivalent command for CLI is `terraform apply --auto-approve --target 'module.example'`
But I am getting the following error when I pass the `targets` in  `ApplyOptions{}` to the `Apply()` function.
Can anybody point me what I am doing wring here?

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/tfexec"
)

func main() {
    // Create a new tfexec.Executor instance
    tf, err := tfexec.NewTerraform("/path/to/terraform/binary")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tf.Init(context.Background(), tfexec.Upgrade(true))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Define the targets you want to apply
    targets := []string{"module.example", "module.another_example"}

    // Create an ApplyOption with the targets
    applyOption := tfexec.ApplyOption{
        Targets: targets,
    }

    // Apply the Terraform configuration with the defined targets
    err = tf.Apply(context.Background(), applyOption)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The error says, `invalid composite literal type tfexec.ApplyOptioncompiler`

```
go run test.go # command-line-arguments ./test.go:23:17: invalid composite literal type tfexec.ApplyOption
```

Comment: What is the **full** error message showing exact lies where it occurs?

Comment: ```
 go run test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:23:17: invalid composite literal type tfexec.ApplyOption
```
@Marcin

Comment: The documentation definitely confirms the error message that is improper usage of `tf.applyOption`. You probably meant to use `tf.applyCmd(context.Background(), Target("target"))`. You can specify additional targets with additional `Target()` `func` members. While this does construct a valid TF command string slice, it is unclear from the docs and source code how to execute it afterwards other than with normal Golang `*cmd.Exec`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard you’re absolutely correct here, I have added the Target using the function and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
    targets := []tfexec.ApplyOption{
        tfexec.Target("module.example"),
        tfexec.Target("module.another_example"),
    }

    // Apply the Terraform configuration with the defined targets
    err = tf.Apply(context.Background(), targets...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, this works exactly as expected